# Gigabyte B550M-K: Sleep mode is borked

Tags: 22.04, gigabyte

I have just built my first PC, I have opted for an AMD Ryzen 9 5950X, RTX 4060 (Galax) case along with an ADATA Legend 800 SSD, however I am experiencing an issue that appears to be related to my Gigabyte B550M-K motherboard. I am unable to put my computer to sleep. the moment I attempt to it instantly wakes back up it appears to root to my motherboard after doing some research, is there any possible way I could fix this?

[This is a recording of the issue (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iFOy4EO2iXfYRyhiDAZ4m7_H81R-UWw-/view?usp=sharing)